# How to align text/video/images on a page with HTML

Tags: html, alignment

I am trying to align an "index" box on the left, and a video on the right, in a webpage I am creating.

I wish for the video box, to be right next to the index box. How do I do this?

I post code, and picture of the website.

[image: how to align index box and video next to each other]

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-/W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Shane Curries Resume in HTML</TITLE>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\CSS\index.css" />
        <style>
        div {
      background-color: lightgreen;
      width: 350px;
      border: 15px solid green;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      </style>
    </HEAD>
    

    <BODY Background="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Contact\Photos\background.png">
        <h1>
        <center>
            Welcome to Shane Duncan Currie's Website
            
        <img src="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\Photos\tree.jpg"width=589 Height=389 ALT="tree">    
            </center>
        </h1>
        <div>
        <p>
        <H2>
        <center>
        <font size=7>Index</font>
        </H2>
        </center>
        </p>
        <center>
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\About\about.html">About me</A></font>
        <br>
        
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Edcuation\Education.html">Education</A> </font>
        <br>
    
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Employment\employment.html    ">Employment history</A></font>
        <br>
        
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Skills\skills.html">Skills</A></font>
        <br>
        
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Contact\contact.html">Contact</A> </font>
        </center>
        </div>
        <br>
        
        <Embed src="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\Video\TestVideo.mp4" align= right>
```

Comment: There are many syntax errors in your code, so you should probably fix those. Anyway, to place two objects next to each other they should share a parent. Look at using floats or flexbox.

Comment: look in to floats or fiexbox, ok got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped the video and the index box in a single div and gave that div (class name `my-div`) display flex;

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-/W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Shane Curries Resume in HTML</TITLE>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\CSS\index.css" />
        <style>
        div {
          background-color: lightgreen;
          width: 350px;
          border: 15px solid green;
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
        }

       .my-div {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
       }
      </style>
    </HEAD>
    

    <BODY Background="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Contact\Photos\background.png">
        <h1>
        <center>
            Welcome to Shane Duncan Currie's Website
            
        <img src="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\Photos\tree.jpg"width=589 Height=389 ALT="tree">    
            </center>
        </h1>
        <div class="my-div">
        <p>
        <H2>
        <center>
        <font size=7>Index</font>
        </H2>
        </center>
        </p>
        <center>
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\About\about.html">About me</A></font>
        <br>
        
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Edcuation\Education.html">Education</A> </font>
        <br>
    
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Employment\employment.html    ">Employment history</A></font>
        <br>
        
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Skills\skills.html">Skills</A></font>
        <br>
        
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Contact\contact.html">Contact</A> </font>
        </center>
        
        <Embed src="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\Video\TestVideo.mp4">
<p>test text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As video will not load here as it is your local video. So i used test text to check

Comment: justify-content: space-between puts the space between the different elements present in the div on which it is applied. If you dont want too much space, you can instead use space-evenly or space-around

Comment: Thanks, I will study up more on this "flexbox"

Answer (score 0):

By using `float: left;` I was able to fix the issue

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-/W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Shane Curries Resume in HTML</TITLE>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\CSS\index.css" />
        <style>
        div {
      background-color: lightgreen;
      width: 350px;
      border: 15px solid green;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      float: left;
      </style>
    </HEAD>
    

    <BODY Background="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Contact\Photos\background.png">
        <h1>
        <center>
            Welcome to Shane Duncan Currie's Website
            
        <img src="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\Photos\tree.jpg"width=589 Height=389 ALT="tree">    
            </center>
        </h1>
        <div>
        <p>
        <H2>
        <center>
        <font size=7>Index</font>
        </H2>
        </center>
        </p>
        <center>
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\About\about.html">About me</A></font>
        <br>
        
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Edcuation\Education.html">Education</A> </font>
        <br>
    
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Employment\employment.html    ">Employment history</A></font>
        <br>
        
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Skills\skills.html">Skills</A></font>
        <br>
        
        <font size=6><A HREF="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Contact\contact.html">Contact</A> </font>
        </center>
        </div>
        <br>
        
        <Embed src="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Index\Video\TestVideo.mp4" align= right>
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```